# Suggestion with tool selection for load, concurrent user testing

Tags: testing, automated-tests, load-testing, performance-testing, android-testing

I have to test windows 8.1 app for tablet. App has to be tested for nearly 1500 users. Technical description: Image file between 2-20 mb will be uploaded and downloaded. With increasing number of user upto 1500 I also have to capture the time required when the user load is say 400, 800, 1200 and finally1500.
Please share your valuable suggestion how can I achieve this with minimum effort as my team is running out of time. I have thought about jmeter, soap ui, load runner. If you know any other tool please share your thoughts.

Comment: If I have missed any detail please let me know.

Comment: I thought of using jmeter to call the api service which are used for image upload and download. Is this correct?? Will this be same as testing the app on tablet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: go with JMeter with JMeter Plugins.

Soap UI is not a load testing tool, but Load UI is. It has a pretty visual interface which is good for beginners, but not so convinient when you have a lot of tests to run. Last time I tryed it there also were some performance issues in the tool itself.

Load runner is good choice if you have some expertise in it (there are a lot of checkboxes and radio buttons). It has a lot of protocols supported and you could "record" the user session and then replay it like it was more users. Sometimes it works out-of-the-box, sometimes you will then need to tune your test.

If you are familiar with your app, the better way is to define the requests which you will be sending to your server manually because that gives you more control. JMeter has a GUI for that. If you go with JMeter you should consider downloading [JMeter Plugins](http://jmeter-plugins.org/) that make load tester's work with the tool much more convinient.

If you want more tools, have a look at:

- [Gatling tool](http://gatling.io/)
- Twitter's [Iago](https://github.com/twitter/iago)
- [Yandex Tank](https://github.com/yandex-load/yandex-tank) (that's the one I use at work for testing web services under heavy load)

I have to mention also that with all these tools you'll be able to measure only the server's performance and not the frontend. Testing the frontend is the different and distinct task. For example you may apply heavy load with JMeter and try to use your app during that in order to see what kind of user experience would you have when there are a lot of users.